# Inspect HTML shows code that view-source can't

Tags: google-chrome

For some random website, I see some text and when I try to search for it in the source I cannot find it but when I open up inspect element and use its search function I can find the text. Why is this and how I can view the full source instead of using the search tool for every code I want to view?

Comment: Is it possible that the HTML of the page either includes inline JavaScript, or is loading JavaScript that is fetching or creating the additional content you see when you are inspecting the page? Without telling us which site you are asking about it is hard to provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Using inspect is not the same as view source.  The inspect tools will give you the DOM tree as it has been parsed by the browser.  That tree may have been modified by any number of things.